# Erro ao gravar uma coleção de checkboxes

Tags: laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.1

Viva,

Estou a utilizar o laravel 5.1 e após submeter um form que tem uma coleção de checkboxes

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "24"
  1 => "26"
  2 => "32"
]
```

Gravo o registo e depois numa tabela relacionada insiro o bloco de registos

```
if( $auto->save() )
        {
            $extras = $request['extra'];
            foreach( $extras as $extra)
            {
                $extra = new AutoExtras;
                $extra->auto_id = $auto->id;
                $extra->extra_id = $extra;
                $extra->save();
            }
        }
```

Isto seria suposto funcionar no entanto, cria o primeiro registo, colocando o extra_id = 0 e dá o seguinte erro:

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 685:
>   Method App\AutoExtras::__toString() must return a string value

Qual o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ***erro*** acontece porque, o mesma nome de variável de instância da classe `AutoExtras` é o mesmo nome da variável que está no `foreach`, é só mudar o nome de uma ou do outro ***exemplo***:

```
if( $auto->save() )
{
    $extras = $request['extra'];
    foreach( $extras as $ex )
    {
        $extra = new AutoExtras();
        $extra->auto_id = $auto->id;
        $extra->extra_id = $ex;
        $extra->save();
    }
}
```